# How can I format SharePoint List View By using multiple conditions

Tags: sharepoint

I want to check the `date` column in my list along with a flag to format list view:

I tried using `AND` and `nested` both don't seem to work:

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": 
       "=if([$DATE] <= @now+2592000000,if([$DateType]=='Expiry',
       'sp-field-severity-severeWarning',''),'')"

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Maybe the sub https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question

Comment: Your syntax for nesting your conditions to create an `AND` effect is correct.  Have you tested both criteria separately successfully?  Are you certain those are the correct internal names of your fields?

Comment: I did check them once again seem to be working just fine individually

Comment: Also tried this:                                      
 { "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(AND([$DATE] <= @now+2592000000,[$DataType] == 'Expiry'),'sp-field-severity--severeWarning','')"
}